# how do you connect and retrieve data from graphite (whisper)

Tags: r, graphite, whisper

Is there an R package to connect to graphite (whisper)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I am looking the same thing. For now I see only that ways:

- Using jsnonlite within R to access [graphite render URL API](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html#graphing-metrics) and get json or csv formatted data.
- Get whisper data from via whisper-fetch (example usage described in [russian IT blog](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.asmadews.ru%2F2014%2F05%2Fgraphite-whisper-wsp-midnight-commander.html) (its automatically translated to English by google)